# i want background image displaying loading in ie, as it is displaying the image after loading fully

Tags: internet-explorer, background, loading

am facing this problem in IE in all versions. Rest browsers it is fine

once i hit this url in IE http://projects.marswebsolutions.com/kidzntoyz6/ , the page seems to be loading normally but the body background the loading part of the image is not displaying. The whole image comes only after it has finished loading. The main problem that am facing is that, i have used a jpeg image for edges nd it is displaying which shuld not be displaying as it looks very ugly..

Please find me a solution, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge on html5 you can use this line...
.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

 <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->


<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

add this in your design page.

Comment: well i tried this thing now, isnt working out.. Its not displaying the background itself now

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick thoughts. Put the X-UA-Compatible tag to the top of the head.

do you have the url to the background image? I don't see any background image in any browser right now and I do not see anything used in the CSS to point to a background image.

Also move the script references to the bottom of your page, and combine the scripts into a single file. I would also minify, gzip and set a futures expires header on the scripts. These are some web performance best practice. You site is nice and fast, but these things can make it faster. I am just a performance geek and I am always checking for these things ;)

Comment: is this the CSS for the background?  #main-bg {background:url(../images/bg-1.jpg) no-repeat center top;}  If so you do not have an element with that id, you might want to move it to the body element.

Comment: thanks for your time, i've put the X-UA tag at the top of the page, & i've moved the id to body, now but its still the same.

i want the body image to show its loading not that it should come after loading fully.